# webpack-dev-server@3.1.14 getting Missing Origin Validation while using npm audit

Tags: security, webpack-dev-server, npm-audit

I have update the `webpack-dev-server` to the latest `3.1.14` but I am still getting vulnerability issue while using `npm audit --fix`. I have tries every thing. cleaning cache. clearing all modules and install again but all same.

Following is the error when I run `npm audit`

```
$ npm audit

                   === npm audit security report ===                        


                             Manual Review                                  
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             

      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           




  High            Missing Origin Validation                                     

  Package         webpack-dev-server                                            

  Patched in      >=3.1.11                                                      

  Dependency of   webpack-dev-server [dev]                                      

  Path            webpack-dev-server                                            

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/725                        

found 1 high severity vulnerability in 60688 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Comment: It is fixed by npm now.. RESOLVED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be due to a typo in the npm vulnerability database. Hopefully fixed soon:
https://npm.community/t/npm-audit-sweems-to-get-semver-wrong/4352

Comment: Yes it is fixed by them now