# NPM severity vulnerability on Angular version 7.1.4

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I just installed the newest version of Angular through 'ng new' and got a High Severity Vulnerability.
After running the Audit, as suggested by npm, I got this:

[image: print with vulnerability issue]

I installed the latest webpack (4.28.3) and webpack-dev-server (3.1.14) versions.

My current devDependicies on packages.json are the following:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.11.4",
  "@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
  "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
  "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~3.1.1",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.4.0",
  "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
  "tslint": "~5.11.0",
  "typescript": "~3.1.6",
  "webpack": "^4.28.3",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.2.0" }
```

As suggested by the correct answer on issue [webpack-dev-server@3.1.14 getting Missing Origin Validation while using npm audit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004545/webpack-dev-server3-1-14-getting-missing-origin-validation-while-using-npm-audi) I tried running the commands on this link: https://npm.community/t/npm-audit-sweems-to-get-semver-wrong/4352/12, which were:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server@latest
```

It merely added the following line to the devDependecies:

```
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
```

But the severity still shows.

Am I still missing something?

**Update from NPM**:
"If you’re still having issues, see https://npm.community/t/npm-audit-sweems-to-get-semver-wrong because some packages have not updated webpack-dev-server and thus, there’s no way to fix this without removing those packages right now."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webpack-dev-server@3.1.14 getting Missing Origin Validation while using npm audit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004545/webpack-dev-server3-1-14-getting-missing-origin-validation-while-using-npm-audi) Do you have this problem today ? It seems like it has been resolved yesterday.

Comment: Tried to solve the problem as suggested by the link on the above correct answer, but I'm still getting the issue.

Comment: Forgot to add the following, even after npm flagged as resolve it still is happening for a number of people, as can be seen here: https://npm.community/t/npm-audit-sweems-to-get-semver-wrong/4352/18

Comment: Yes then I guess we just have to wait for the npm team to fix this...

Comment: Update by NPM: "If you’re still having issues, see https://npm.community/t/npm-audit-sweems-to-get-semver-wrong because some packages have not updated webpack-dev-server and thus, there’s no way to fix this without removing those packages right now."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to latest Angular version solves the problem (version 7.2.1).